# CSS Animation for Specific Div

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I have done some css animation with help of articles over internet. However, when i put this animation, it goes all over body. but i need it only in **Container-fluid** div.
how do i contain this?
I tried overflow:hidden, bt it doesn't work.
code is as follows. (i have put a specific body size for this here, for you to understand it. When i put it in my website, it goes all over .

```css
body {
  width: 1366px;
  height: 1366px;
}

.anim_Main {}

.bg {
  animation: slide 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #fed900 50%, #D71920 50%);
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50%;
  opacity: .5;
  position: fixed;
  right: -50%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bg2 {
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration: 7s;
}

.content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: .25em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* left: 50%; */
  /* padding: 10vmin; */
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  /* top: 50%; */
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.contentNews {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: .25em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(25%);
  }
}

.widthMax {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="widthMax">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="purifier">
          <div class="bg"></div>
          <div class="bg bg2"></div>
          <div class="bg bg3"></div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="card-title" align="center">Lorem Ipsum..!</h3>
        <p class="drop-cap">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
          publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. &rdquo;
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src=""></a>
        <br /><br />
        <a href="#" class="card-link" target="_blank">
          <h5 align="center">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
          <p align="center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> <i>Lorem Ipsum</i>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: how far is it meant to go?

Comment: only inside this section, container-fluid.
But it goes on complete body.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `.content` to be the context of non-static positioned elements, and to hide the overflow:

```
.content {
  position: relative; /* already exists */
  overflow: hidden;
```

The `position` of `.bg` is `fixed`, change it to `absolute`, so it will be in the context of `.content`.

```
.bg {
  position: absolute;
```

```css
.container-fluid { 
  width: 50vw; /* just for the demo */
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  animation: slide 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #fed900 50%, #D71920 50%);
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50%;
  opacity: .5;
  right: -50%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bg2 {
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration: 7s;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: .25em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* left: 50%; */
  /* padding: 10vmin; */
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  /* top: 50%; */
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.contentNews {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: .25em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(25%);
  }
}

.widthMax {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="widthMax">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="purifier">
          <div class="bg"></div>
          <div class="bg bg2"></div>
          <div class="bg bg3"></div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="card-title" align="center">Lorem Ipsum..!</h3>
        <p class="drop-cap">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
          publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. &rdquo;
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src=""></a>
        <br /><br />
        <a href="#" class="card-link" target="_blank">
          <h5 align="center">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
          <p align="center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> <i>Lorem Ipsum</i>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I need one clarification. if i need to apply the same to another div, what should i change?

Comment: The container should have `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden`. The animation should have `position: absolute` and not fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude <3 Much appriciated.